# How to format yticks or xticks as percent seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-visualization

I am trying to format the yticks here as percent. So show 10%, 20%, 30%

```
   ax = sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]},index=[0.1,0.2,0.3]))
```

[image]

I have tried this but it gives the wrong ticks

```
ax = sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]},index=[0.1,0.2,0.3]))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PercentFormatter` doesn't work because it changes the tick labels according to the tick values. However, the ticks in this case are `[0.5, 1.5, 2.5]` so you see `50%...`.

You can manually reformat the tick labels:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]},index=[0.1,0.2,0.3])
ax = sns.heatmap(df)
ticks = ax.set_yticklabels([f'{x:.0%}' for x in df.index],
                           va='center')   # to center the label vertically
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Maybe also center the labels vertically? `ax.set_yticklabels(..., va='center')`

Comment: Thanks Please add this to your original answer to help others @Quang Hoang